# Set Button Click handler with a DataTrigger

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to update some visual properties and the click handler on a button in response to the value of an enum. The visual properties are easy enough, but the click handler is giving me trouble.

The enum has 4 values: Launching, Launched, Terminating, Terminated. The button will launch or kill a process based on the current state. Here's what I have for the visual properties:

```xml
<Button>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ProcessState}" Value="{x:Static local:ProcessState.Launching}">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="false"/>
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Launching..."/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ProcessState}" Value="{x:Static local:ProcessState.Launched}">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="true"/>
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Terminate"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ProcessState}" Value="{x:Static local:ProcessState.Terminating}">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="false"/>
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Terminating..."/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ProcessState}" Value="{x:Static local:ProcessState.Terminated}">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="true"/>
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Launch"/>

                    <!-- Doesn't work!
                    <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="LaunchSim_Click"/>
                    -->
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

The problem is that `Style.Triggers` doesn't support `EventSetter` so I can't update `Button.Click` with this approach. Now, I *could* using a single click handler and branch based on the enum, but I want to understand what is possible from the XAML side.

I also tried creating 4 separate styles in `Button.Resources` then swapping out the styles with `DataTrigger` but then you end up trying to change the button style using a style and I'm not convinced that works either.

Is there a reasonable way to change `Button.Click` from XAML in response to a changing data value?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a reasonable way to change `Button.Click` from XAML in response to a changing data value?

No, there isn't. Using a single click handler and branch based on the enum sounds like a good idea. Alternatively, if you are familiar with the MVVM design pattern, you could bind to a command of a view model and handle your logic in there. It is indeed possible to set the `Command` property using a `Setter` in a `Style`, but remember that XAML is a *markup* language and just because you possible *can* do certain things in pure XAML, it doesn't mean that you always should.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of EventSetter you can do

```
<Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding SomeCommand}"/>
```

Actually if you want a button to be clickable only in one state of enum you can just bind to "SomeCommand" and create a command which is enabled only when particular enum type is selected.

for example

```
<Button Command={Binding SomeCommand} >
   Style...
</Button>
```

In a view model you can do

```
SomeCommand = new RelayCommand(SomeMethod, ()=> ProcessState == ProcessState.Terminated);
```